# Curly bracket issues - R - ifelse statement within for loop

Tags: r

I have a code that is failing to work because of curly bracket issues

```
o1 = read.table('/Users/manshi/Desktop/PSYC57H3/PSYC57_Homework3/Object1.csv', header=TRUE, sep=",")
PredictedValue = vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 100)
PredictionError = vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 100)
PredictedValue[1] = 0
AlAccepts = vector(mode = 'logical', length = 100)
for (trial in 1:100){
  ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == FALSE, 0, 1) {
    PredictionError[trial] = o1$Reward[trial] - PredictedValue[trial]
    PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial] + .3*PredictionError[trial]
  } ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == TRUE, 0, 1) {
PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial]
  }
}
```

The error message that I am getting is:

```
> for (trial in 1:100){
+   ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == FALSE, 0, 1) {
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"for (trial in 1:100){
  ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == FALSE, 0, 1) {"
>     PredictionError[trial] = o1$Reward[trial] - PredictedValue[trial]
>     PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial] + .3*PredictionError[trial]
>   }   ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == TRUE, 0, 1) {
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial]
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in r, there is both the ifelse() function and the if(){}else{} construct. I think you were looking for the latter.

Comment: You should change `ifelse` to `else if`

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse (AlAccepts[trial] == FALSE, 0, 1)` is a function and results in a return value, in this case 0 or 1. Further conditioned excecution is not done so the following brackets show a syntax error. Using `else if(){}` should work as you intended:

```
for (trial in 1:100){
  if (AlAccepts[trial] == FALSE) {
    PredictionError[trial] = o1$Reward[trial] - PredictedValue[trial]
    PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial] + .3*PredictionError[trial]
  } else if(AlAccepts[trial] == TRUE) {
PredictedValue[trial + 1] = PredictedValue[trial]
  }
}
```